# TMC beans: The JDK is missing and is required to run some NetBeans modules

Tags: java, netbeans

I am new to programming and started the MOOC.FI course (https://www.mooc.fi/en/installation/netbeans) I am running Windows 10. I downloaded both TMC beans 1.4.0, as well as Eclipse Temurin JDK with Hotspot 11.0.12+7(x64).

When I open Netbeans, it says

> The JDK is missing and is required to run some NetBeans modules Please
> use the --jdkhome command line option to specify a JDK installation or
> see http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqRunningOnJre for more information.

I tried :

- Uninstalling and redownloading both the JDK and TMC beans.
- Changing the tmcbeans.conf file, changing the file to:
  #jdkhome="C:\Program Files\Eclipse Foundation\jdk-11.0.12.7-hotspot"
- Adding:
  netbeans_jkdhome="C:\Program Files\Eclipse Foundation\jdk-11.0.12.7-hotspot"

Both haven't stopped TMC Beans from returning the same message.

EDIT:

The problem is fixed, I downloaded OpenJDK 8 with hotspot from https://adoptopenjdk.net/archive.html?variant=openjdk11&jvmVariant=openj9

Then, I added the line
'jdkhome="C:\Program Files\Eclipse Foundation\jdk-8.0.302.8-hotspot"' to the tmcbeans.conf file. I found it at C:\Program Files\TMCBeans\etc.

After this, the message no longer appears.

Comment: Update your question with all of the following: [1] The version of NetBeans being used. [2] A link to the MOOC.fi course you are taking. [3] A link to the download page for TMC beans. [4] A link to the download page for Eclipse Temurin JDK. This allows others to emulate what you did in order to reproduce/resolve your issue. Without that information your question may be closed due to lack of details.

Comment: I added the site link to install both TMC beans and Eclipse Temurin JDK. How do I find the version of Netbeans being used?

Comment: [1] OK. I see the download for TMCBeans in the link you provided, but no link for "Eclipse Temurin JDK", and the MOOC.fi instructions for "Installing Java" state to use "AdoptOpenJDK11". Can you clarify why you are installing "Eclipse Temurin JDK"? [2] You can obtain the version of NetBeans being used, and also the version of Java being used by NetBeans, from the **Help > About** window.  Please update your question with that information. [3] You had successfully installed and run NetBeans before doing anything else described in your question, right?

Comment: AdoptOpenJDK11 is now rebranded to Eclipse Temurin JDK. The sight says 24th July 2021: AdoptOpenJDK is moving to the Eclipse Foundation and rebranding.
Our July 2021 and future releases will come from Adoptium.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried downloading the older JDKs from - https://adoptopenjdk.net/archive.html?variant=openjdk11&jvmVariant=openj9?

EDIT 20/08/21
The University of Helsinki is aware of the issue and they are working to resolve it.